# Route MIC input through headset and at the same time AUDIO output through same headset

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetoothheadset

In my app, I need to take input voice(surrounding noise)from the headset and at the same time need to play some tone as output sound in the headset.

However, during the search, I found that it is not possible to input the noise and send the output as sound/music. But with voice calls, When using Bluetooth SCO the input (microphone) and output (speaker) audio are managed separately by the system. During a phone call, Android's telephony stack handles this functionality, enabling both the microphone input and speaker output through the Bluetooth SCO connection.

I have used below to use the headset mic.

```
audiomanager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

is there any way to take input from the headset and send output some music) at the same time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You've given us some statements. But, you didn't actually ask something. Please edit the question, and explicitly tell us what you want to do.

Comment: What kind of headset exactly? And what type of audio are you trying to play? IIRC, SCO is limited to 8 or 16 kHz.

Comment: Yes, I'll play sound tones from 125 Hz to 12.5kHz (some targeted tones in this range). It is BLE and BRD type headphone, and for android we are using BRD.